# Use SASS instead of SCSS on Ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

our team has finished build html style based on dot SASS files. I tried to use that sass file in Ionic 3. But, i cant find a way to use SASS file in Ionic 3. All docs and suggestions are using dot SCSS files.

Is there any way to use custom styling for Ionic 3 besides of changing variable.scss file or any dot SCSS files? I need to change major style for this app which use our own style.

Maybe i can use complied main.css from sass (builded with gulp) for ionic 3?

I tried to put complied main.css on `src/assets/style/main.css` and import that file in `app.component.ts` with:

```
styleUrls: ['/assets/css/main.css']
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: Danu it dsoesnt matter to the CSS file if you are using .sass or .scss. Once its compiled to .css, .css is all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

`.sass` and `.scss` basically means the same thing, since both files contain the same, or at least should, AFIK. That is just a naming thing, so you can either rename the file, or create symlink like so:

```
ln -s main.sass main.scss
```

Comment: how about code? In my sass file not using semicolon and use tabbing, it will cause error